# Alpha Matte not keying out video?

Tags: transparency, compositing-nodes

In [this](https://youtu.be/1eQst8SAVRE?list=WL&t=293) tutorial, Kenan Proffitt goes through the very simple process on how to use a matte key (picture 2) to key out a video with rotoscoping. I have duplicated his exact process by using a "Set Key" node with the video clip plugged into the "Image" input and the rotoscoped matte plugged into the "Alpha" input. (picture 1) It's fairly straightforward. But when I do that, the result is only half-way working. The rotoscope subject is perfectly still there while the background is only sort of transparent-not 100% transparent (picture 3). **Why is this happening?**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha channel needs to be associated to the image. Use an Alpha Convert node and choose Straight to Premultiplied.

[image]