# Key Color still shows in sort of a torn manner

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am keying an image and I have a problem on the screen: the Key Color is showing in some sort of a torn manner.

[image]

---

EDIT:

I keyed out the blue color, but other colors still remain.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alpha Matte not keying out video?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210436/alpha-matte-not-keying-out-video)

Comment: So I used tips in the answer, and this is the result. [Blender Screen](https://imgur.com/a/tHKYxhE)

Comment: Your problem is that the image is very poor quality, all of the artifacts (called macro-blocking) is due to the compression (an image in jpeg format most likely).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the alpha channel generated by the keying node has to be [associated](https://hg2dc.com/2020/08/26/question-25/) with the picture. Use an [Alpha Convert](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/alpha_convert.html#alpha-convert-node) node in *straight to premultiply* mode.

[image]

The artifacts at the top of the image are caused by the compression on the original image. Some compression algorithms for video work by considering similar colors to be one solid block of color, usually this is not as visible, but since you are using this area for keying, the [macro-blocks](https://www.intraway.com/blog/introduction-to-digital-video-compression/) become visible.

[image]

What that means is that the color you are keying out is not even.

The solution are:

- Use an image that has less or no compression.
- Change the threshold of tolerance for the key, either by modifying the *Key Color* or by modifying the values for *Clip Black* (pixels that are considered part of the background) or *Clip White* (pixels that are considered foreground)
  Read the manual for this node:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/matte/keying.html